# Relay to switch 50 lines at once?

Tags: relay

I'm looking to allow two cartridges to be inserted into a slot that normally only accepts one (more specifically, Nintendo 64 cartridges). I can't just toggle the power lines to each cartridges because of backfeeding. What sort of device would I need to use to switch a large number of lines from one cartridge to another (an N-pole single throw relay)? In this case, there isn't much power passing through the lines, but in a more general sense what component would one need to actuate multiple switches in a near-simultaneous timeframe?

Comment: You could use a couple analog muxes like the 74HC4052 to do that. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9907

Comment: There's a similiar question here that has a few ideas http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58428/best-way-to-build-a-64-bit-output-multiplexer

Comment: Electropneumatic pipe organs often include a number of 61-pole relays (one contact for every key on the keyboard), but from what I've seen they don't usually include solenoids directly.  Instead, they usually have a small electrically-operated air valve, and then a bellows-operated 61-pole switch.  Pipe organs naturally have an adequate supply of slightly-pressurized air, and an electrically operated valve needs less current than a solenoid large enough to activate a 61-pole switch.  Still, I think some pipe organ makers like Wicks use direct electric relays.

Comment: The Wicks parts price list doesn't list relays (either electrically or electro-pneumatically operated) but if you still need a 61-pole switch you might try contacting them.  I think pipe organs generally use 24 volts, but that should be safely isolated from all the contacts.

Answer (score 2):

The [ADG3300](http://www.analog.com/en/interface-isolation/level-translators/adg3300/products/product.html) is usually used as a voltage translator, but will work fine with the same voltage on both sides. Pulling the EN input low tristates the Y pins (on the inside) and pulls down the A pins (on the cartridge), virtually disconnecting the two sides from each other. A couple of power MOSFETs will allow you to control V+ and GND.